# Marry a cousin uncle

Tags: halal-haram, nikah

I am deeply in love with a boy who is son ky grandfather's own sister. it means that he is cousin of my father. so is it appropriate to marry him or not according to Islam?

Comment: I'm confused: "cousin uncle" vs. "son ky grandfather's own sister" vs. "cousin of my father".  Which is it?

Answer (score 2):

Marriage is only forbidden with the stated relatives mentioned in the following verses:

> [Quran 4:22](https://quran.com/4/22) And do not marry those [women] whom your fathers
>   married, except what has already occurred. Indeed, it was an
>   immorality and hateful [to Allah ] and was evil as a way.
>
> [Quran 4:23](https://quran.com/4/23) Prohibited to you [for marriage] are your mothers,
>   your daughters, your sisters, your father's sisters, your mother's
>   sisters, your brother's daughters, your sister's daughters, your
>   [milk] mothers who nursed you, your sisters through nursing, your
>   wives' mothers, and your step-daughters under your guardianship [born]
>   of your wives unto whom you have gone in. But if you have not gone in
>   unto them, there is no sin upon you. And [also prohibited are] the
>   wives of your sons who are from your [own] loins, and that you take
>   [in marriage] two sisters simultaneously, except for what has already
>   occurred. Indeed, Allah is ever Forgiving and Merciful.

With the words fathers, mothers, daughters and sons being also applied perpetually to all direct ascendants and descendants (grand-children and grand-fathers etc.) For details on these see [Hidayah](https://archive.org/stream/Hedaya_201703/Hedaya#page/n279/mode/2up) and [Minhaj Al Talibeen](https://archive.org/stream/minhaj_al-talibin_english#page/n307/mode/2up).

Cousins are not mahrams and can be married. The Prophet Muhammad (p.b.u.h) married [Zaynab bint Jash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zaynab_bint_Jahsh), who was his cousin. The same would extend to cousin uncles.

**Edit:** As [Armaan](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/20796/armaan) noted in the comments, Fatimah, the daughter of the Prophet, married her father's cousin, Ali ibn Talib.

Comment: so can I marry him or not because he is cousin of my father ??

Comment: @ArzooShaikh Yes you can.

Comment: You can marry him, good luck! :)

Comment: @Arzoo Shaikh  The Prophet Muhammad's (PBUH) daughter Fatima married her father's cousin. Ali was the cousin of the Prophet and he married the Prophet's daughter, Fatima.